# Subtract one %parent row total from another in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have created a pivot table base on some columns and change values to custom calculation % parent row total. Now I need to subtract one % parent row total from another % parent row total in pivot table and it should show in the existing pivot table. For example Sale1 is 10% and Sale2 is 12% then result is (10-12)=2%.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: I think you will have to do this outside the Pivot Table.  The problem is that the idea of "subtracting one from another" requires some agreement on the order of subtraction.  This becomes complicated if you have more than 2 entries where you can have combinations of subtractions.  If referencing data outside the Pivot Table, you can use the GETPIVOTDATA function.

Comment: Thank you so much Byron for your prompt reply. After spending two days on it, I have reached on the conclusion that excel does not have functionality to do minus in %parent row total in pivot table same as you suggest. - Deepak Giri